# Can I send data to signalr clients as a Class?

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr

I've recently made this function in my hub:

```
public void createFileAndWrite(string path, string content)
        {
            Clients.Others.createFile(
                new CreateFile
                {
                    UserName = users[Context.ConnectionId],
                    Path = path,
                    Content = content
                });
        }
```

Seems OK, but when I built my project, my website couldn't connect to SignalR Hub. This error appeared in browser console:

```
SignalR: Error loading hubs. Ensure your hubs reference is correct, e.g. <script src='/signalr/js'></script>.
```

So I deduced, that it's blame of my CreateFile class. And it was; after removing those lines, everything works perfectly. In every other function in Hub I used strings to pass information.

The interesting fact is: it didn't work on my website client (where I used javascript to connect with server) but everything seemed to work fine on c# client (windows application).

So, do I really can't use my own classes to organize data that I want to send? I can't find anything about that on asp.net site.

Comment: You can send anything to signalR that can be serialised to json. What does CreateFile look like?

Comment: @KiwiPiet: It contains 2 strings and two booleans

Comment: Did you follow the instructions in the error message?

Comment: @mason: Did you read my question? Of course I had this "/signalr/js" reference on my site, because it worked before.

Comment: @Ludwik11 Yes, I read your question. But when things go wrong, you don't make assumptions. You narrow down the possibilities by ensuring things are set up correctly.

Comment: @mason: so, yes, I checked if this <script> is present, I've also checked if this path exists. It does. Unfortunately, even after serializing my object to json and sending it as a string, it doesn't work ;/

Comment: Look in the Network tab of your browser's developer tools. Does it successfully pull down the /signalr/js stuff?

Comment: @mason I think I found reason. In one of my server Hub functions I used nullable variables and it seems that exactly caused a problem. You couldn't help me, because I didn't paste all code, I'm sorry and thanks for trying to help me ;)

Comment: And I'm still disgusted that signalr didn't return any errors

Comment: @Ludwik11 might want to add that as an answer and flag it as answered...